# InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Can't compare test expression of type [Facility] with element of type [basicType@4(java.lang.Integer,4)]]

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, entity-framework-migrations

```
[dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Can't compare test expression of type [Facility] with element of type [basicType@4(java.lang.Integer,4)]] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't compare test expression of type [Facility] with element of type [basicType@4(java.lang.Integer,4)]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.SqmCriteriaNodeBuilder.assertComparable(SqmCriteriaNodeBuilder.java:2098)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.SqmCriteriaNodeBuilder.equal(SqmCriteriaNodeBuilder.java:2121)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.SqmCriteriaNodeBuilder.equal(SqmCriteriaNodeBuilder.java:182)
    at com.freit.medicalservice.repository.specification.PatientSpecification.lambda$facilityIdEqual$2a154287$1(PatientSpecification.java:139)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.SpecificationComposition.toPredicate(SpecificationComposition.java:62)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.SpecificationComposition.lambda$composed$e1dcbe07$1(SpecificationComposition.java:49)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.SpecificationComposition.toPredicate(SpecificationComposition.java:62)
```

I remain stuck on this silly error for 2 days that I was getting on JPA specification after I migrated from spring and its related packages(including JPA, Hibernate) from version 5 to 6.

The line I was getting error on;

```
public static Specification<Patient> facilityIdEqual(Integer facilityId) {
        return (root, query, builder) -> {
            if (facilityId != null) {
                query.distinct(Boolean.TRUE);
                return builder.equal(root.join("patientFacilities").get("facility"), facilityId); //throws error 
            }
            return null;
        };
    }
```

Where patientFacilities is of type PatientFacility (JPA Entity) and facility is of type Facility (JPA Entity)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

simple change 
root.join("patientFacilities").get("facility") 
to 
*root.join("patientFacilities").get("facility").get("id")*

Basically the error was that Facility (JPA entity type) was not a match for Integer id. Earlier version of spring (version 5) supported query like root.join("patientFacilities").get("facility") on referenced tables via joined column name but in Spring 6 (JPA 6, Hibernate 6) we have to be specific in types of the db table columns.